# Git repository on external disk?

Tags: git, version-control

I am setting up git server on linux Debian and I want for all of my repositories to be saved on external disk (usb disk drive). How can I acomplished that?

Comment: see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2129214/backup-a-local-git-repository

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just place them all there. OTOH, it makes litle sense, as they won't be accessible when the external drive isn't plugged in.

`git` repositories are just plain directories full of normal files, that can be backed up, copied and moved around at will. What I do with my *really* important stuff is to have an external repository (on another machine I have set up a bare `git` repository for the project) and now and then I push any changes over (OK, around once a day). Others that I share are also on a local git server will all bells and whistles. Same idea as before, changes are regularly uploaded,